# how to call popup window while ajax callback post method waiting to response in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

**1) my call back function**

```
function fetch_servicedata1() {

    var filename = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentMain_hdnfile").value;
    companyID = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentMain_hdnCompanyID').value;
    var service_Res = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UtilityService.asmx/New_FatchCacheXMLString",
        data: "filename=" + filename + "&CompanyID=" + companyID+"&Rq_CID=1",
        dataType: "xml",
       // cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (xml) {
            // alert('first relsut');

            if (xml.documentElement.text) {
                fnFetchResult_New(xml.documentElement.text);
            }
            else {
                fnFetchResult_New(xml.documentElement.textContent);
            }
            if(TotalResultCount>0)
                document.getElementById("divProgressBar").style.display = '';
            secondPagingFlag = true;
            console.log('before func 2');

           // setTimeout(fetch_servicedata2(), 1);
          },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //    alert(xhr.status);
         //   alert(thrownError);
          //  $('#waitScreen').css('display', 'none'); $('#waitBox').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
```

**2) my event**

```
$(".external-link").live("click", function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,      
        url: "",
        success: function () {
            window.open("HtlIntermediate.aspx");
        }
        })
});
```

i need to event call without wait for call back success
i have called call back function and it will take around 1 minute to response and in the meantime need to click on the button and open popup window which show data from database using asp.net

Comment: So you want to call click function of external-link right after ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use beforeSend and complete parameter in jquery ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,   
    beforeSend:function(){window.open("HtlIntermediate.aspx"); },
    complete:function(){//close window
    },
    url: "",
    success: function () {
         // process other stuff
    }
    })
```

Comment: hi friend, i am calling 2 hit to hotel service for display hotel result, my first hit response within 5 second and second hit response will take approx 40 second, so after 1 hit result user like to see hotel details so it's not working whenever second hit post not success, so i cannot use  beforeSend, i need to not block my any link for second hit..kindly reply ASAP..